# Setting variables inside for loops

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop

I've written some code to filter through a dictionary and change URLs to their UIImage representation. Here's my code:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSDictionary *json = appDelegate.json;

for (id section in json) {
    NSArray *key = [json objectForKey:section];
    if ([key isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        for (NSMutableDictionary __strong *entry in key) {
            entry = [entry mutableCopy];
            for (id value in [entry allKeys]) {
                if ([value isEqualToString:@"pic"]) {
                    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[entry objectForKey:value]]];
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    [entry setObject:image forKey:value];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

appDelegate.json = json;
```

The iteration is correct, because when I breakpoint my code, I see a UIImage variable for pic instead of a string. However, I find that if I continue executing, it reverts back when I'm out of the for loop.

My data scructure is very weird so I've provided a screenshot of it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZsLU.png).

Comment: You never modify `json`. Why do you expect to see different results?

Comment: I'd advise against updating the dictionary with `UIImage` representations if you have anything other than an trivial number of images, because images can require a great deal of memory. Better to do lazy loading (i.e. only retrieve the images as they're needed), or if you absolutely want to prefetch them, save them to your `Documents` folder and optionally update your mutable array/dictionary/model to reflect that. And if you insist on prefetching the images into memory, make sure you respond to `didReceiveMemoryWarning` to save them to persistent storage and free up their memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rmaddy was exactly right. I was trying to change `entry`, and expecting it to also update `json`. I ended up changing this:

```
[entry setObject:image forKey:value];
```

to this:

```
// Changes the json variable directly
[[[json objectForKey:section] objectAtIndex:i - 1] setObject:image forKey:value];
```

Comment: All you have to do is to remove this line:`entry = [entry mutableCopy];`.

Answer (score 1):

your code here: `entry = [entry mutableCopy];` , you create an new `NSMutableDictionary` and assign it to entry, all you have done have influences on it only.

Comment: Is there any way around this? @KudoCC

Comment: @JoshuaGeorge  Make a completely different mutable array outside the for loop and then, inside the for loop, save stuff into that mutable array as you go. (You can see stuff outside the for loop from inside the for loop.) This is a completely standard technique.

Comment: @JoshuaGeorge I wonder if the entry is mutable, why you create another mutable dictionary, just use it.

Answer (score 0):

Please add you Json also so that it will be easy for us to correct answer 
but from you code its clear that you are tyring to change the Dictionary which you are looping. Which you can not ! You need to set different Mutable Dictionary and assign those values. Something like this

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSDictionary *json = appDelegate.json;
    NSMutableDictionary *finalJson =  [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (id section in json) {
        NSArray *key = json[section];
        if ([key isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            for (NSDictionary *entry in key) {
                for (id value in [entry allKeys]) {
                    if ([value isEqualToString:@"pic"]) {
                        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:entry[value]]];
                        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        [finalJson setObject:image forKey:value];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    appDelegate.json = finalJson;
```

This will create finalJson Dictionary of only image .. if that is what you need. 
But if you need finalJson with other values then you need to assign objects at each loop

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
NSMutableDictionary *json = [appDelegate.json mutableCopy];
```

completely is:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSMutableDictionary *json = [appDelegate.json mutableCopy];

for (id section in json) {
    NSArray *key = [json objectForKey:section];
    if ([key isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        for (NSMutableDictionary __strong *entry in key) {
            entry = [entry mutableCopy];
            for (id value in [entry allKeys]) {
                if ([value isEqualToString:@"pic"]) {
                    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[entry objectForKey:value]]];
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    [entry setObject:image forKey:value];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```